# Vehicle Crash DataSet with Accelerometer

Tags: data-request, transportation, accelerometer

I am looking for an open dataset of vehicle crashes that includes the vehicle location, heading, speed and accelerometer data. Availability of Gyro and Magnetometer data is a plus but not necessary.

Comment: Hi did you finally find a good dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the closest dataset I can think of. It doesn't have all of the detail you are looking for but it goes back many years.

[FARS data](http://www.nhtsa.gov/FARS)